# Your cache folder contains root-owned files

Tags: node.js, npm

Trying to run npm ci on a git deployment branch for my website but receiving the following error;

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /home/storm/.npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1010:1010 "/home/storm/.npm"
```

I tried running the command it suggests but this doesn't work because there's no such file or directory of  "/home/storm/.npm"

I can't find any answers online! Please help

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to solve the described issue. It depends on how you run npm.

**Option 1:**
Adapt the access rights on the npm cache files / folder. Just run the suggested command where 'storm' is your user name and '1010' are your user ID and group ID. (User ID and group ID sometimes differ.)

```
sudo chown -R 1010:1010 "/home/storm/.npm"
```

**Option 2:**
Remove the npm cache by running the following command:

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
```

**Option 3:**
Instruct npm to user another directory for caching (avoid using the default npm cache folder). Run the following command before running npm.

```
export npm_config_cache=/path/to/cache
```

In my case I ran yarn / npm in a CI/CD pipeline on a Jenkins agent and faced the same issue. Option 3 worked for me. I adapted my pipeline and replaced the command

```
gradle testAndCoverageWithYarn
```

with

```
export npm_config_cache=npm-cache && gradle testAndCoverageWithYarn
```

(The gradle task `testAndCoverageWithYarn` calls yarn / npm.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and this command worked for me:

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
```

If this issue sill occured try :

```
sudo chown -R 1010:1010 "/home/storm/.npm"
```

Good Luck ;-) I hope it works for You! Watch out for typos ..